# ARDUINO: SEND GPS DATA TO FIREBASE USING GSM SIM800L

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm, arduino-ide

I'm trying to send the data that I got in GPS module to Firebase the real time database using GSM SIM800L but sadly it always got zero result the latitude and longitude. I already tested the GPS module and it's working. How to solve this problem... Please help me if you know the solution.. Your help is very helpful..

THIS IS THE RESULT I GOT:

```
POST:/Jeepney1.json?auth=yzZb6JRN6pHMoDxdtUPHhyhrCL0R1WtP9TPBWKM3
Data:{"Latitude":0.000000,"Longitude":0.000000}
Status code: 200
Response: {"Latitude":0.Longitude":0.0}
O
POST:/Jeepney1.json?auth=yzZb6JRN6pHMoDxdtUPHhyhrCL0R1WtP9TPBWKM3
Data:{"Latitude":0.000000,"Longitude":0.000000}
Status code: 200
Response: {"Latitude":0.Longitude":0.0}
```

AND THE CODES I USE:

```
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 256
 
#include <TinyGsmClient.h> 
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>  
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
TinyGPSPlus gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

#define rxPin 7
#define txPin 8
SoftwareSerial sim800(txPin, rxPin);
 
const char FIREBASE_HOST[]  = "famous-segment-319603-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com";
const String FIREBASE_AUTH  = "yzZb6JRN6pHMoDxdtUPHhyhrCL0R1WtP9TPBWKM3";
const String FIREBASE_PATH  = "Jeepney1";
const int SSL_PORT          = 443;
 
char apn[]  = "internet.globe.com.ph";
char user[] = "";
char pass[] = "";
 
 
TinyGsm modem(sim800);


TinyGsmClientSecure gsm_client_secure_modem(modem, 0);
HttpClient http_client = HttpClient(gsm_client_secure_modem, FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);
 
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
 
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(96000);
  Serial.println(F("device serial initialize"));
 
  sim800.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("SIM800L serial initialize"));
 
  Serial.println(F("Initializing modem..."));
  modem.restart();
  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  Serial.print(F("Modem: "));
  Serial.println(modemInfo);
 
  http_client.setHttpResponseTimeout(10 * 1000); //^0 secs timeout
}
 
void loop()
{
 
  Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
  Serial.print(apn);
  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, user, pass))
  {
    Serial.println(F(" fail"));
    //delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  Serial.println(F(" OK"));
 
  http_client.connect(FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);
 
  while (true) {
    if (!http_client.connected())
    {
      Serial.println();
      http_client.stop();// Shutdown
      Serial.println(F("HTTP  not connected"));
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      gps_loop();
    }
 
  }
 
}

void PostToFirebase(const char* method, const String & path , const String & data, HttpClient* http)
{
  String response;
  int statusCode = 0;
  http->connectionKeepAlive(); 
  String url;
  if (path[0] != '/')
  {
    url = "/";
  }
  url += path + ".json";
  url += "?auth=" + FIREBASE_AUTH;
  Serial.print("POST:");
  Serial.println(url);
  Serial.print("Data:");
  Serial.println(data);
 
  String contentType = "application/json";
  http->put(url, contentType, data);
 
  statusCode = http->responseStatusCode();
  Serial.print(F("Status code: "));
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  response = http->responseBody();
  Serial.print(F("Response: "));
  Serial.println(response);
  
  if (!http->connected())
  {
    Serial.println();
    http->stop();// Shutdown
    Serial.println(F("HTTP POST disconnected"));
  }
 
}
 
void gps_loop()
{

    String  latitude = String(gps.location.lat(),6);
    String  longitude = String(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    
  String Data = "{";
  Data += "\"Latitude\":" + latitude + ",";
  Data += "\"Longitude\":" + longitude + ""; 
  Data += "}";
   
  PostToFirebase("PATCH", FIREBASE_PATH, Data, &http_client);
   
   
}
```

Comment: Just so you know. You should never put your database URL especially not in combination with your database secret on the internet. You should really go into the Firebase console create a new secret and deactivate the old one.
I would also be interested if you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: Did you sorted out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

probably because your gps module isnt providing the gps coordinate ,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

because of you are using both modules with software serial communication with arduino. Arduino get confused. my solution is either you use hardware serial for one of the module or while communicating with both module software serially you want to implement logic at a time only one software serial begin second one stop the start second software serial and stop first

my opinion is you should use hardware serial for one of the module

```
TinyGPSPlus gps;
HardwareSerial& gpsSerial = Serial; // HardwareSerial for GPS module
```